# Aid to understand conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory

I have a hard time to understand conditional expectation, that is $\mathbf{E}[X| \mathcal{G}]$ where $X$ is a random variable on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbf{P})$ and $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{A}$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra. There are already good questions and answers here, but still...

Okay, let's say that we throw a fair coin three times with outcomes $H$ (heads) and $T$ (tails), so $\Omega = \{H, T\}^3$ with $\mathcal{A} = 2^\Omega$ (power set). Now the real random variable $X$ shall be defined as the number of heads thrown. So the graph of $X$ looks like:
[image]

Now we define $G := \{\omega \in \Omega : \text{number of heads is even}\}$ and let $\mathcal{G}_1:=\sigma(G)$, then the graph of $\mathbf{E}[X|\mathcal{G}_1]$ looks like:

[image]

If we define $\mathcal{G}_2$ as the sub-$\sigma$-algebra generated by the sets $\{(T,T,T),(T,T,H)\},\; \{(T,H,T), (T,H,H), (H,T,T)\},\; \{ (H,T,H), (H,H,T), (H,H,H)\}$, then the graph of $\mathbf{E}[X|\mathcal{G}_2]$ looks like:

[image]

Ok, in the case of finite probability spaces I just could have written down all the values of $\mathbf{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]$. In the *really* interesting/problematic case of infinite probability spaces this is not possible.

But could there be a similar visualization for conditional expectation of random variables defined on infinite probability spaces and where $\mathcal{G}$ is infinite, too? So that one can build an intuition of $\mathbf{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]$?